# FOSUserbundle sends email properly, I cannot

Tags: email, symfony, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

I have successfully configured the FOSUserBundle. It properly sends activation email.

My config_dev.yml is like follows:

> ```
> ...
> swiftmailer:
>     transport: gmail
>     username:  my_username@gmail.com
>     password:  my_password
>     disable_delivery:  false
> ```

My parameters.yml is like follows:

```
parameters:
    ...
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: null
    mailer_user: my_username@gmail.com
    mailer_password: my_password
```

Problem starts when I try to do the following (very basic):

```
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Please sign up to ProJacked!')
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo($emailaddress)
    ->setBody($this->renderView('HR/invitationemail.txt.twig'));
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

The code runs properly but emails are sent "in debug mode", so I see them in the profiler but are not actually sent. What am I missing? I know it's something super simple :/

Comment: is this email being sent out through a command or through a normal web controller action?

Comment: Inside the controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Symfony standard edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/app/config/config.yml), `app/config.yml`, Swift spools emails to memory by default:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host: "%mailer_host%"
    username: "%mailer_user%"
    password: "%mailer_password%"
    spool: { type: memory }
```

You can remove the `spool` line to prevent memory spooling.  You can also flush the queue manually (which is usually needed for console commands), although [Symfony claims](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#using-memory-spooling) that this step is no longer necessary past Symfony 2.3+ and Swiftmailer 2.3.5+

```
$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool(); // $mailer is the mailer service
$transport = $container->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');

$spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

Finally, make sure you follow steps for Gmail as outlined here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

Comment: Did you try just using the defaults instead of going through gmail?  Did you check your spam folders?  Did you follow the steps through http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html ?  Did you try it in production mode?

Comment: I solved it, mails simply got spooled (God knows why considering that I never told swiftmailer to spool).

Comment: Glad you solved it. Swiftmailer usually defaults to spooling in memory.  Were you sending the email via a command?  Because if so you definitely have to flush the queue manually as shown here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

Comment: It's always scary to solve something without knowing how but no, I was sending the message inside the controller

Comment: Look in config.yml because there's a default swiftmailer config in there with memory spooling by default

Comment: You got it, there it was! ;) Thanks again!

Comment: No problem - I updated my answer to include all of the information from these comments so if someone comes back to this they'll see that first.